# CORBA error org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN minor code: 202 completed: No

Tags: corba

We have developed Server-Client application using CORBA.
When client try to make a request to Server, we get below error message.

```
    Jan 14, 2018 10:00:22 AM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl writeLock
WARNING: "IOP00410202: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection close: rebind"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionCloseRebind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionCloseRebind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.writeLock(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.finishSendingRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
```

What we observed that, whenever client make continuous 5-6 requests, client gets the above error for particular 2-keys. Sometimes first 4 requests work correctly but get the error on last request. Or sometime gets the error on first request then remaining requests work correctly.
I have done enough search on google but did not find the solution.
I hope someone will help me here.

Answer (score 1):

COMM_FAILURE means the underlying connection failed somehow. In your case, you're experiencing a premature close of the connection.

You reported only a warning message. Do you experienced an COMM_FAILURE exception in your code or are you seeing this only in log messages? In my guess this seems only a ORB internal log message and, if I'm right, it's not a problem at all.

In some very simple hello world code you could experience this when you execute the server without a orb.run() in your server, or even you're doing a System.exit while processing the invocation.

In other hand, I recommend you to use http://JacORB.org implementation instead of old and unsupported Sun implementation for CORBA (built-in the Oracle JVM). JacORB is a mature implementation and it's compliant to CORBA 3.0 spec.